# apache files upload shredding the files from temporary directory

Tags: java, apache, file, upload

I am using the commons file upload library for files uploading. I can still see the files in the temporary folder after the successful upload (only sometimes, else they are deleted after the upload). Are these files recoverable, if yes how can we make sure if its shredded before being deleted?

Comment: Could you please provide some code? If you use `DiskFileItemFactory`, no files should be deleted as stated in its javadoc, unless you configured `FileCleaningTracker` (or there is some external tool which does it)

Comment: Yes, I have configured the **FileCleaningTracker**. My question is will these deleted files be recoverable by recovery tools? As these files may be confidential and the upload api writes them to the temp directory in an unencrypted state.